# Using JSON Parse push to open fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, parse-platform, android-json

I have successfully got an iOS app to open certain views according to a value stored in a JSON push and I am now trying to do the same in our android app.

This is the message being sent:

```
{
 "alert": "Test Push ",
 "title": "New Test push",

 "view": "circles"
}
```

There have been quite a few questions on stack overflow about this but I'm afraid I don't understand where the particular code snippets can go, or how to make it open a fragment rather than the root activity.

My question is, without asking for all of the code to be written for me, what functions, calls and classes do I need to use in order to achieve this?

Comment: you want to open different views depending on data in your push or you need to open the same view with different data?

Comment: Different views depending on the push

Answer (score 1):

I implement Parse Push with this solution: [Open activity by clicking on the push notification from Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842571/open-activity-by-clicking-on-the-push-notification-from-parse/28153931#28153931)

You best bet would be writing an Intent reader to detect if the Activity is started from clicking a Push message. The above link has an example for you:

```
try {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data"); // Get data from Parse Push json
        JSONObject json;
        json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String view = json.getString("view");
        // Write your logic to start the fragment/activity
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```